# PCIe Host controller driver - issue with resource allocation

Tags: kernel, device-driver, pci

I am developing a PCIe host controller driver based on Synopsys DW IP. This is based on x86 and no BIOS programming is available here.
So, I need to do the init coding in ARM way which is available at arch/arm/kernel/bios32.c.
I am reusing drivers/pci/host/pcie-designware.c driver available in mainline 3.14 kernel.
My End Point (EP) device needs to be programmed with two memory spaces of 4K into BAR0/1 and BAR2/3 registers as non-prefetchable.

Now, I am able to enumerate the EP device on BUS 1, I can read device/vendor ID, Class and capabilities. But unable to see BARs at EP getting programmed correctly.

In DT file, with ranges I have provided one memory as IO mem and one as mem space like as follows:

```
  #address-cells = <3>;
#size-cells = <2>;
ranges = <0x00000800 0 0xe4480000 0xe4480000 0 0x00002000 /* configuration space */
      0x81000000 0 0          0xe4482000 0 0x00001000 /* downstream I/O */
      0x82000000 0 0xe2083000 0xe4483000 0 0x00001000>; /* non-prefetchable memory */
```

Now I see these are not getting populated as bus 1 resources (rather as bus 0 resource).
I understand the bus 0 is for the bridge and bus 1 is behind the bridge connecting EP device.
How can I make sure these resources to be allocated for bus 1?

my lspci result is as follows:

```
/sys/bus/pci # lspci
00:00.0 Class 0604: f00d:8087
01:00.0 Class 0d40: d00f:8086
```

I feel, I can hardcode these BAR programming in my driver and still make it work.
But I want to allocate these resources properly, so that pci driver (test driver for communicating with EP) get to use the pci_dev and it's resource to extract all these information without hardcoding.

My dmesg at the time of scanning bus 1 looks like as follows:

```
[  123.710000] pci 0000:01:00.0: [d00f:8086] type 00 class 0x0d4000
**[  123.710000] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff 64bit]
[  123.710000] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0x00000000-0x000000ff 64bit]
[  123.710000] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x20: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
[  123.710000] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x24: [mem 0x00000000-0x0000ffff]
[  123.710000] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0x00000000-0x000007ff pref]**
[  123.710000] pci 0000:01:00.0: supports D1
[  123.710000] pci 0000:01:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D3hot D3cold
[  123.710000] pci 0000:01:00.0: PME# disabled
[  125.230000] pci_bus 0000:01: bus scan returning with max=01
[  125.230000] pci 0000:00:00.0: scanning [bus 01-01] behind bridge, pass 1
[  125.230000] pci_bus 0000:00: bus scan returning with max=01
[  125.230000] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 5: can't assign mem (size 0x10000)
[  125.230000] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 0: can't assign mem (size 0x1000)
[  125.230000] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 4: can't assign mem (size 0x1000)
[  125.230000] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 6: can't assign mem pref (size 0x800)
[  125.230000] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 2: can't assign mem (size 0x100)
[  125.230000] pci 0000:00:00.0: not setting up bridge for bus 0000:01
```

I am very new to PCIE and learning while implementing the same.
Any suggestions or pointers are highly appreciated.